# @DateTimeFormat issue different time between server and client

Tags: java, spring, annotations, locale, datetime-format

I have a problem with spring annotation @DateTimeFormat. The issue is that it does not take the correct time zone from the string. In my code I have this:

```
@RequestHeader(HDR_START_DATE) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    @ApiParam(required = true, name = HDR_START_DATE, value = START_DATE_FORMAT) final Date sDate,
@RequestHeader(value = HDR_END_DATE, required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = STANDARD_DATE_FORMAT)
    @ApiParam(name = HDR_END_DATE, value = END_DATE_FORMAT) final Date eDate
```

Here i am trying with iso and pattern to test both ways, but none of them works.

For example in the query i send this string for date: "2015-03-03T00:00:00+0000", but in the server log i see it is parse to Mon Mar 02 21:00:00 ART 2015. as you see it take 3hs off. The server default locale is California, and the client is Argentina, that is why  there is 3hs of difference.

Comment: Actually, that's just 3 hours off. And that's the exact difference between ART and UTC. The ISO formatted date indicates the time in UTC.

Comment: You are right, is just 3 hours off.

Comment: Then the parsed date is correct.